# Binding Static variable

Tags: wpf, binding

I have this Model:

```
class Person
{
    public static int Counter;
    public string _firstName;
    public string _lastName;

   public string FirstName
   {
        get {return _firstname; }
        set
        {
            _fileName = value;               
        }
   }

   public AddPerson(Person person)
   {
       Counter++;
   }
}
```

Now i try to binding My Counter `property` into simple `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Name="tbStatusBar" Text="{Binding Person,Source={StaticResource Person.Counter}}" />
```

And got this error: The recourse Person.Counter could not be resolved.

Comment: you could do `Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Person.Counter}}"` but it won't auto refresh as you won't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for static properties/fields

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide an alternate binding scenario. Long story short, you will need at least one object available to the visible or logical tree to ultimately bind `Counter` to...

Answer (score -1):

Binding requires properties and not fields. Change `Counter` to be a property and bind to it directly such as

```
Text="{Binding Counter}"
```

---

Binding in Xaml requires an item on the visual or logical tree to actually bind off of. See [Trees in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391(v=vs.100).aspx). The static property `Counter` exists but not in a location where binding can find it.

So either create a Person object on the page's resources (you may need to make the Person class public so the namespace resolution can find it) such as:

```
<local:Person x:Key="myPerson"/>
```

and bind to it such as

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}"
           DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource myPerson}}">
```

Or if the TextBlock's data context has access to one of them such as a valid (non null) List of Person objects (for this example) called 'Persons' as shown below:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Persons[0]}" Text="{Binding Counter}"/>
```